# Is it possible to do IP SLA in linux?

Tags: linux, sla

Is it possible to do static route tracking using IP SLA in Linux? What I want to do is something like this:

I have two internet connections(ADSL and Wimax) connecting to switch. Use ADSL line if you can not reach 8.8.8.8 change default gateway and use Wimax.

Is it possible to do something like this? Or I will need another router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Is it possible to have multiple uplinks?  Certainly.
- Is it possible for some application in Linux to switch between the multiple uplinks?  Sure.
- Am I aware of any existing applications to do this? No, you would probably have to write a script or use a tool like monit to periodically check that the links are up, and then update your routes appropriately.